# CSS error: background image display problem

Tags: html, css

two background-image:

https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Slim-landing%20banner1906x810-03.jpg

https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/V-face-landing%201906x810_R1-02.jpg

You can open each one in the browser.
I can display the first one image, but the first is replaced by the second URL, it doesn't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="background-image:url(https://www.marsha.com.hk/libs/img/Slim-landing%20banner1906x810-03.jpg);  
        height: 330px;
        background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       position: relative" class="item2" data-aos="fade-up">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When does it have to replace?? unclear..

Comment: replace the url

Comment: do you use js or jquery? do you have any button?

Comment: code in above only

Comment: if you want the complete background to show use "background-size: contain"  also try to set a width of 100%

Comment: @ChSunrain Please accept John's answer so we can see you don't need help anymore with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the complete background to show use 
`background-size: contain` 
 also try to set 
 `width: 100%`